# How to use export csv button on transactions grid in magento' admin transactions menu under sales?

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento

I am trying to export the transaction data into csv.
To achieve this I have added following line of code

```
$this->addExportType(’*/*/exportCsv’, Mage::helper(’sales’)->__(’CSV’));
```

to

“protected function _prepareColumns()” function in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Transactions/grid.php file.

Also I have added an action exportCsvAction in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php

```
public function exportCsvAction()
{
$fileName = ‘transactions.csv’;
$grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(’adminhtml/sales_transactions_grid’);
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

Now, when i try to export the transactions data I get error saying “You cannot define a correlation name ‘sop’ more than once”.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score -1):

Just use this free module and it should take care of your issues:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-order-export.html

Comment: Sarvagya is looking for help in programming. Answer bypasses the question.